# SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running error while shutting down tomcat server.

Tags: tomcat, server, shutdown

tomcat server is starting multiple number of times but not shutting down. http://localhost:8080/ is blank
here's the error code in terminal. how to get around this ?

```
sudo sh shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /var/lib/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/lib/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /var/lib/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/var/lib/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Nov 23, 2015 4:00:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
Nov 23, 2015 4:00:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:498)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:430)
```

Comment: this error means tomcat is already shutdown. check your log file to trace route cause and copy paste here

Comment: The evidence you've presented suggests that it isn't even started.

Comment: Any updates on this? I also encountered the same issue....

Comment: @JenSze There is nothing to update. Tomcat wasn't running.

Answer (score 1):

find the document which in `jdk1.x.x_xx/jre/lib/security/java.security`

modify the securerandom.source to  `securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom`

then it's normal.

this is a bug of jdk.

Comment: Nonsense. How exactly can a random-number bug cause 'connection refused'?

Comment: And what alleged 'bug of JDK' is this?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem today,it maybe a bug with jdk-1.8.x.

For example,my jdk path is **"/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144"**.

`cd /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/security/`

find the file which named **"java.security"**,

```
vi java.security
```

find **"securerandom.source=file:/dev/random"**.

Modify **"securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom "**.

Then,go to the Tomcat/bin directory, execute `./start.sh`and `./shutdown.sh`,find that everything is all right.

Comment: The `./` part is redundant, and the rest doesn't make sense. The Tomcat shutdown protocol doesn't use HTTPS, as can be seen from the stack trace, and 'connection refused' isn't caused by a TLS problem.